# Creating Azure My SQL - unable to create an available server name

Tags: azure, azure-mysql-database

I am trying to create a MySQL Server in the Azure Free Trial but it doesn't matter how random or specific I enter the Server Name under the Server Details, it is returning an error stating that the "Server name must be available"

Create MySQL Server
[image: Create MySQL Server]

Comment: You can change the location and try again. If this issue still exists, it my be the restriction of free subscription. You can raise a support ticket on azure portal by following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create Virtual Machine (with Ubuntu will be best for MySQL)
Then when this is done, you will create the MySQL server and in the Server Name you will put the same name as Virtual Machine computer name. (give some time and a lot of refresh (Ctr+F5) )

Be aware that the resource group should be the same for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it happens when you first set your account or make changes to your account/subscription or create a new directory, you just need some patience and a lot of (Ctr+F5) it will work afterwards.